# How to find a JavaScript variable's transitive usage through function calls?

Tags: javascript, parsing, esprima

Suppose I have access to the full set of source that could potentially be using a JavaScript variable `foo`.

Some of the source code looks like this:

```
foo.bar = 'baz';

(function(a, b, c) {
    a();
    b.bar = 'whee';
    c();
}(fn, foo, fn));
```

Are there any tools available (ESLint rules, NPM modules, etc.) that could identify all usages of the `foo` variable here? I'm after a list of all access of the variable, including within scopes and including nested objects. So, it would have to identify:

- The `foo.bar` usage in the global scope
- The `foo` usage in the function invocation
- The `b.bar` call is an access of `foo.bar`

Comment: And what about eval'd strings that reference the variable?

Comment: `b.bar` does not use the variable `foo`.

Comment: You can track down all (non-`eval`) references to the identifier `foo` (and also whether it is in scope for an `eval` call), but you cannot track all accesses on a particular object without executing the code (which comes down to the halting problem)

Comment: @Bergi how does it not use `foo`?

Comment: @thomas: The variable `foo` is not used in the expression `b.bar`. The object that `foo` points to might (depending on a lot of things) be the same as the one `b` points to, but that's a whole different topic.

Comment: @Bergi you're right. I used the word "variable". I suppose what I mean is "things that access the same object reference". The list of the outcome I want is correct, even if the words I used are not.

Comment: @Chris: Ok. In that case, [it's impossible in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @Bergi isn't the halting problem to do with determining whether executing a given program will halt? Static analysis of a program should yield a result, and the halting problem is irrelevant, unless I am misunderstanding the connection..?

Comment: @Chris: Tell me whether `var foo = {}, b = {}; if (arbitraryFunctionThatMightNotHalt()) { b = foo; } b.bar = 'whee';` will ever reach the `b.bar` assignment with the `foo` object. You can't do that with static analysis.

Comment: @Bergi it will: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=var%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20b%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%20if%20(arbitraryFunctionThatMightNotHalt())%20%7B%20b%20%3D%20foo%3B%20%7D%20b.bar%20%3D%20'whee'%3B because static analysis treats a program as an input string, it doesn't execute the program

Comment: @Bergi but I see your point now. I'm not concerned about the actuality in execution, so much as the potential for it. I'm also willing to ignore and constrain the problem to assume the root object definition is not reassigned or re-evaluated

Answer (score 2):

http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#infer seems like a good lead:

```
infer.findRefs(ast: AST, scope: Scope, name: string, refScope: Scope, f: fn(AST, Scope))
Will traverse the given syntax tree, using scope as the starting scope, looking for references to variable name that resolve to scope refScope, and call f with the node of the reference and its local scope for each of them.

infer.findPropRefs(ast: AST, scope: Scope, objType: Obj, propName: string, f: fn(AST))
Analogous to findRefs, but used to look for references to a specific property instead. Whereas findRefs is precise, this is dependent on type inference, and thus can not be relied on to be precise.
```